# How to create a Swift like Extension to add Constraint in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a swift code example in which UIView passed in an array and set its constraint like below:

```
extension UIView {
    func addCnstraintsFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var Allviews = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            Allviews[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: Allviews))
    }
}
```

and in swift, it can be used as following

```
self.view.addCnstraintsFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views:View1)
```

Now I want to create this type of code in Objective-C **(I can't use the swift code in my project)**. So can anybody let me How to achive this goal with Objective-C

So Here is My Objective C Code Which I've Tried:

Here is My Code:

**UIView+MyCnstCategory.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface UIView (MyCnstCategory)
    -(void)addCnstraintsFormat:(NSString *)format views:(NSArray <UIView *> *) views;
    @end
```

**UIView+MyCnstCategory.m**

```
 #import "UIView+MyCnstCategory.h"

    @implementation UIView (MyCnstCategory)

    -(void)addCnstraintsFormat:(NSString *)format views:(NSArray<UIView *> *)views {
        /*  App got Crashed just before this line.........  */
        NSLog(@"views = %@", views);
        NSMutableDictionary *Allviews = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSInteger i = 0;
        for (UIView *view in views) {
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%ld",(long)i];
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [Allviews setObject:view forKey: key];
        }
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: format options: 0 metrics: nil views:Allviews]];
    }
    @end
```

And When I called This Category Code Like below:

**MyVC.m**

```
#import "MyVC.h"
#import "UIView+MyCnstCategory.h"
#import "myCustomUIViewClass.h"


        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

        myCustomUIViewClass *MySubview = [myCustomViewClass new];
        [self.view addSubview: MySubview];
        /* When The Following Code called the App Got Creashed just after calling this method */
        [self.view addCnstraintsFormat: @"H:|[v0]|" views: @[MySubview]];
        }
```

**myCustomUIViewClass.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface myCustomUIViewClass : UIView
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
    @end
```

**myCustomUIViewClass.m**

```
#import "myCustomUIViewClass.h"

@implementation myCustomUIViewClass

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        return self;
    }
@end
```

Can anybody let me know what I'm missing...

Comment: refer from here -> https://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/

Comment: For objective-c you can create a category class of UIView instead of Extension which is in swift.

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface UIView (ConstraintsFormat)

- (void)addCnstraintsFormat:(NSString *)format views: ...; //Here I don't know how to implement arguments list in objective c

@end

@implementation UIView (ConstraintsFormat)

- (void)addCnstraintsFormat:(NSString *)format views: ... {
    //Here your code from question
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm facing Crash when I tried the same Review My question I've added My Code also.